# Mount a subdirectory of an NTFS mount with different ownership

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I would like a user without sudo to be able to read and write a subdirectory of an NTFS HDD.

I would like my main user to have read/write access to all the filesystem.

As far as I can tell, I can't change permissions using a bind mount, and I can't directly mount only a subdirectory of an NTFS HDD.

Is there a way to do what I want?

[Mounting ntfs subdirectories of device](https://superuser.com/questions/698274/mounting-ntfs-subdirectories-of-device?rq=1) hints at the same problem, but doesn't provide the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the NTFS-3g driver, mount the filesystem with permission checking enabled – either by using the **`permissions` mount option** in fstab, or by [creating an UserMapping file](https://superuser.com/a/697237/1686).

Then you'll be able to `chown` each directory to a different user.

Comment: This works.  It appears that if you change permissions on the NTFS mount having mounted like this, they persist across reboots.

Comment: @wilbo: Yes, they are stored internally as NTFS ACLs, and should be visible from Windows as well (although the translation is imperfect).